# family drugstore or pharmacy

Tags: phrase-meaning

Man: Sometimes when I'm not feeling well or the doctor tells

me I need certain drug or medication, I go around the corner to the

**family drugstore or pharmacy** and I get what I need. Excuse me miss.

---

What does "**family** drugstore" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a drugstore owned by a family.

A large company with many drugstores is not a family drugstore--that would be a franchise.

*Family drugstore* brings to mind a small, friendly pharmacy.